# How can I perform a backend search with ng-select using a `?q=...` HTTP parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using `ng-select` 7.2.0 in an `Angular` 12 app.

The data that I need to make available to ng-select consists in tens of thousands of entries, so I don't want to pre-load all that data into `ng-select` to let it perform a frontend filtering when you type.

Instead, I would like `ng-select` to use my backend as a data source and pass an argument, e.g. `q`, with what the user is typing to trigger the auto-complete.

E.g. if the user types `"foo"` into the input field, I would like `ng-select` to perform an HTTP `GET` against my server with `?q=foo` as a parameter. The backend would then perform the filtering and only return the items that match `foo`.

Then the user can select which one they want among those.

I didn't find a mention about this on this page:

https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources

I understand that the `[items]` input of `ng-select` can get an Observable, but how can I access the value that the user is typing to search, and then update the `[items]` input to use that value as the `?q=...` parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ng-select` as a `(search)` output. When that event is emitted, I can update the `[items]` input with a new observable that uses the updated API call.

Comment: can you share some code example ?

Comment: this method works but can anyone tell me how do i disable local search once my items are loaded

Comment: @VikasKandari set `[searchFn]="returnTrue"` on ng-select element, and in your component create function `returnTrue(): boolean { return true; }`. Ng-select will keep performing its inner search, but searchFunction will always return true. Therefore the list won't get narrowed down